# http.post not working in angular 2

Tags: javascript, http, angular, error-handling

Why is my http.post not working in angular 2. Just can't figure out what I have been missing.

Here is login.component.ts file

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
model: any = {};
loading = false;

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private alertService: AlertService
){}

ngOnInit(){
    // reset login status
    this.authenticationService.logout();
}

login(){
   let errMsg: string;
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log('Success');
                //this.router.navigate(['/']);
            },
            error => {
                console.log('Error');
                this.loading = false;
            }
        );
}
```

Here is the authentication.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService{

private baseUrl = '..';

constructor(private http: Http){}

login(username: string, password: string): Observable<Response>{
    let body = JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password});
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/api/auth/login`;

    return this.http.post(url, body, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);

}

logout(){
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
}

private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

Here is the routes file

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

   // otherwise redirect to home
   { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
 ];

 @NgModule({
     imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
     exports: [ RouterModule ]
 })

 export class AppRoutingMoudle{}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: any error in console? does `AuthenticationService` has `Injectable` decorator on it?

Comment: no, theres some error but my app quickly logs back to login page. and more over. I get this on the URL: http://localhost:3000/?username=test&password=test . So, why does it show the params in URL since it is a post request

Comment: Tell me what you expect to see in the URL while making a call to API.

Comment: I expect a result whether its success or error response. But I don't intend to see the params in the URL while making POST request.

Comment: Did you check your network tab in chrome dev tools? So that we can learn  if you actually make the post call..

Comment: I have checked but my page seems to redirect back to login page at once.

Comment: You can check the "Preserve log" checkbox to save the history.

Comment: Have you tried with `HashLocationStrategy`? What server are you using? Do you have `<base href="/">` set?

Comment: yes I have it at index.html  <script>document.write('<base href=" ' + document.location + ' " />');</script>

Comment: I got this error core.umd.js:3004 EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/login/login.component.html:17:42 caused by: this.http.post(...).map(...).catch is not a function. But I am following the docs here.

Comment: which version of rxjs are you using? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13125 this might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http, Response,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


@Injectable()
```

import these above your services , then do it on constructor

```
 constructor(private _http:Http) { }
```

then youcan use it with this._http.post